# multiple column sum in codeigniter table

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In my view file i am generating a table as following

```
<?php
foreach ($accounts as $row) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['total_online_sale'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['product_price'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['discount'] . '</td>';
}
?>
```

I want to generate sum values of those columns in a row surrounded by `<tfoot>` tag.
I don't want to do this operations in model. how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so,sum up values in your loop and after loop print these values in `<tfoot>` tag

```
<?php
$total_online_sale= 0;
$product_price=0;
$discount =0;
foreach ($accounts as $row) {
$total_online_sale += $row['total_online_sale'];
$product_price +=$row['product_price'];
$discount +=$row['discount'];
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['total_online_sale'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['product_price'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['discount'] . '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '<tfoot>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $total_online_sale . '</td>'; //Grand sum for column total_online_sale 
  echo '<td>' . $product_price . '</td>'; //Grand sum for column product_price 
  echo '<td>' . $discount. '</td>'; //Grand sum for column discount
  echo '</tr>';
echo '</tfoot>';

?>
```

Comment: If I enable pagination this shows only the paginated results sum only. I still don't want to do this operation in model, is it possible to show entire sum in paginated page?

Comment: @Alvi_1987 its better if you ask another question with all the concerns you have and also provide me the link of question so i ll try my best